# Token-based authentication steps

Tags: authentication, token

I searched the Internet for days about how to conduct a token-based authentication but still not 100% sure. As far as I know, it contains the following steps according to [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/token-based-authentication-securing-the-token):

1. When the client log in for the very first time, it sends the username **U** and password over SSL to the server.
2. The server check if the username and password are correct. If they are, the server generate a token, which contains the HMAC of **U** and token issuance time stamp **T**, keyed by a static cryptographically strong key **K**. The token is then sent to the client.
3. In the following request sent from the client to the server, the token is included. Then the server can decode the token using **K** and check if it is valid.

I am confused becaues there is a totally different method, please refer to [link](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence). The step should be:

1. When the client log in for the very first time, it sends the username and password over SSL to the server.
2. The server generate the token and store it in a table. At the mean time sent to the client, which is stored in cookie.
3. In the following request sent from the client to the server, the token is included. The server check if the token sent exist.

Which method should be chosen?

Please help~